# Is it possible to print the JAVA_HOME path used by a specific profile from command line without starting the server in WebSphere

Tags: websphere, websphere-8

With `managesdk.sh` or `managesdk.bat` I can get the version of the JDK used by a specific profile using the following command:

```
managesdk.bat -listEnabledProfile -profileName myProfile
```

and it prints something like:

```
CWSDK1004I: Profile myProfile :
CWSDK1006I: PROFILE_COMMAND_SDK = 1.8_64
CWSDK1008I: Node liferay-node SDK name: 1.8_64
CWSDK1009I: Server server1 SDK name: 1.8_64
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.
```

However, it will be better for what I want to do if I can execute a command to get the actual JAVA_HOME path. I know it will be printed when starting the server and I can find it in SystemOut.log.

However, is there any command to print it out without starting the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the path to your profile on-disk:

`(unset JAVA_HOME; source profiles/XXX/bin/setupCmdLine.sh; echo $JAVA_HOME)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're willing to do a little bit of parsing (if you need the path in a variable), you can use the `-verbose` option on some commands to print extra properties:

```
managesdk.bat -listEnabledProfile -profileName myProfile -verbose
```

which will dump out some extra properties, including the SDK path (look for `com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location`.)

```
CWSDK1004I: Profile dmgr90 :
CWSDK1006I: PROFILE_COMMAND_SDK = 8.0_64 
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.8.0_64=8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.8.0_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java/8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.8.0_64=linux
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.8.0_64=x86_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/linux/x86_64/
CWSDK1008I: Node dmgrNode SDK name: 8.0_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.8.0_64=8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.8.0_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java/8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.8.0_64=linux
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.8.0_64=x86_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/linux/x86_64/
CWSDK1009I: Server dmgr SDK name: 8.0_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.version.8.0_64=8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.bits.8.0_64=64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.location.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/java/8.0
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.platform.8.0_64=linux
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.architecture.8.0_64=x86_64
 - com.ibm.websphere.sdk.nativeLibPath.8.0_64=${WAS_INSTALL_ROOT}/lib/native/linux/x86_64/
CWSDK1001I: Successfully performed the requested managesdk task.
```

See the documentation here: [managesdk command](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEQTP_9.0.0/com.ibm.websphere.base.doc/ae/rxml_managesdk.html)